# Windows dual boot - Hibernate and restart

Tags: linux, multi-boot, hibernate

I have a machine with Windows10 on SSD and Linux on external USB.
they both work fine!

On some scenarios, I would like to jump from one OS to another and keep the state between them - that's when Hibernate comes to assist.

BUT I WANT MORE!

Is there a way to Hibernate and reboot the machine?
because the default behavior of hibernation is to turn off the machine after the memory is dumped to the disk.

I've found a [way to do that on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703511/hibernate-and-restart-immediately-instead-of-powering-off) but couldn't find a way to do that from Windows...

Comment: Hibernating will lock the NTFS filesystem of Windows, making it unwritable by Linux. You OK with that?  If not, then please run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1` in Linux, then come back here, click [edit], and let us know what you have, so we can see if your CPU supports virtualization (some don't). Please don't post that with a Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: @K7AAY I'm not near this machine now. I also don't want virtualization, all I want is to hibernate&reboot from windows. I'm also OK with the read-only issue of NTFS while in hibernation. Do you still want me to edit the post with the machine details - the machine is quite new and supports virtualization (I7 Kaby lake)? Is there any command that will allow me to hib&restart win10?